# iOS - Reading from a txt file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, text-files, mainbundle

I am storing level details inside of a text file within my iOS project. The Text File contains the following:

**Level1.txt**

```
    LevelNum:1.0
    weaponPickupRate:10.0
    weaponPickupAmount:20
    monsterMinSpeed:8.0
    monsterMaxSpeed:12.0
    monsterRate:1.5
    levelMonsters:10
    goldPerMonster:10
```

I am reading the text file using the code below:

```
    fileName = "Level1.txt"
    levelPath = "\(NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!)/\(fileName)"

    var err: NSError? = NSError()
    let s = String(contentsOfFile: levelPath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)

    println(s)
```

When I run this using the iOS Simulator - iPhone 6, everything works fine and it prints the data from the text file.

When I run this directly on my iPhone 6 it prints `nil` and does not read the text file.

Why is this?

Cheers
Ryann

Comment: Dump out the file path and then use Xcode Organizer to check if it's really there.

Comment: try using this instead and see what it retuns   `levelPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Level1", ofType: "txt")`